# logic fault with reversing the order of vector elements using std::swap

Tags: c++, swap

i have an exercise on chapter 8 of programming principles and practice by Strostrup ,it asks to write function that uses std::swap to reverse the elements of `vector<int>` here's my code

```
void rev_vect(vector<int>& v) {
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
            swap(v[i], v[v.size() - 1- i]);
}
```

the problem is that this function doesn't reverse the elements and the vectors passed to it remain the same, i have tried to see if there is something wrong with my function but unfortunately i wasn't able to find anything suspicious!, please help me to see what's wrong with the function
i apologize if my question lacking formality as i'm new to programming.

i know that the vector subscript operator returns a reference to the vector elements and `std::swap()` swaps the values of it's arguments so i thought my logic should be correct.

Comment: Recommendation: Get familiar with whatever debugger cam with your development tools. With a debugger you can step through the code at your pace, usually line-by-line, and watch what happens as it happens. You'd have seen what was going on a few steps after you hit the middle of the loop and wouldn't have had to ask this question.

Comment: Even something as simple as printing the vector after each swap would have illustrated the error.

Comment: Agreed. The key is to give yourself enough information to see what the program is really doing. If you can see what the program really does and you put that up beside what the program is supposed to do so you can see the difference, most bugs become so obvious that you want to slap yourself for making them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you pass though all the container, you swap elements twice which brings them to the initial state.

The correct code would be:

```
void rev_vect(std::vector<int>& v) {
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size()/2; i++)
        std::swap(v[i], v[v.size() - 1- i]);
}
```

See the [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/8Ye6x3cvE)